# My sort method and find/count method are messing up and I have no idea what's wrong?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, methods, text-files

I have to write a program that sorts names alphabetically while removing duplicates and counting the amount of times the names appear and capitalizes all of it. My partner and I have been working on this and have found no way to have the sorting method work properly and have the program find and count the times the names appear. We have to use certain methods to do this...which I linked the pdf down at the bottom. I really want to understand what's wrong and why the output is not coming out right.

```
public class Names {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static ArrayList<String> fnArray = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> lnArray = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    getNames(fnArray, lnArray);

    sort(lnArray);
    find(fnArray,1);


    capitalize(fnArray,lnArray);

}

public static void getNames(ArrayList<String> fn, ArrayList<String> ln) throws IOException {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What file would you like to read from ?: ");
    String n = kb.next();

    File inputFile = new File(n);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String firstName = in.next();
        fn.add(firstName);
        String lastName = in.next();
        ln.add(lastName);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < fnArray.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(lnArray.get(i) + " " + fnArray.get(i));

    }

}

public static void capitalize(ArrayList<String> fnArray, ArrayList<String> lnArray) {

    String capfn = " ";
    String capln = " ";

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    System.out.println("****************Names***************");
    while (i < fnArray.size() && j < lnArray.size()) {
        capfn = fnArray.get(i);
        capln = lnArray.get(j);
        String capFname = capfn.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + capfn.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        String capLname = capln.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + capln.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        fnArray.set(i, capFname);
        lnArray.set(i, capLname);
        System.out.println(lnArray.get(j) + ",  " + fnArray.get(i));
        i++;
        j++;
    }

}

public static void display(ArrayList<String> names) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(names.get(i));
    }

}
public static int find(String s, ArrayList<String> a) {
int count = 0;
for (String str : a) {
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
        count++;
}
return count;   }

public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> s) {

    for (int j = 0; j < s.size(); j++) {
        int i = -1;
        while ((i = find(s, j)) >= 0) {
            s.remove(i);
        }
    }
}

public static void backwards(ArrayList<String> names) {

    for (int i = names.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        names.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < names.size(); i++) {
            if ((names.get(i).equals(names.get(j)))) {
                names.remove(i);
            }

        }

    }
}
public static void sort(ArrayList<String> array) {

    for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {

        // find the index of the ith smallest value
        int s = i - 1;

        for (int j = i; j < array.size(); j++) {

            if (array.get(j).compareTo(array.get(s)) < 0) {

                s = j;

            }

        }

        // swap the ith smallest value into entry i-1
        String temp = array.get(i - 1);

        array.set(i - 1, array.get(s));

        array.set(s, temp);


    }


}




 public static void showUnique(ArrayList<String> names){
    System.out.println("Unique name list contains:");
    for(int i=0 ;i< names.size() ;i++){

         System.out.println(lnArray.get(i) + " " + fnArray.get(i));
      }

  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Collections.sort()` method to sort an array list; once it is sorted, you will have entries like this:

```
 ArrayList = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Beta", "Gamma", "Theta", "Theta" ... }
```

The important point to note, however, is that the duplicates will be next to each other in the sorted array.

Finally, if you want to remove duplicates, you can put all the elements of the ArrayList into a Set: set is a data-structure which removes duplicates.

Example:

```
Set<String> foo = new HashSet<String>( yourArrayList );
```

EDIT: Use this approach which is both: easy and simple-to-comprehend.

```
for( int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++ )
{
    for( int j = i + 1; j < array.size(); j++ )
    {
        if( array[i] > array[j] )
        {
            // Swap the contents of array[i] and array[j].
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! The problem is we cant use any .sort methods, we have to have it under public static void sort (ArrayList<String> names) and it has to be a nested loop and it has to refer to the arraylist  stored in a text file.

Comment: @AmyTenorio I have updated the answer to include a more easily interpretable version of sorting. Can you please try that.